# In NodeJS, convert database query output to Json format

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

This is my code:

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "user",
    password      : "password",
    connectString : "gtmachine:1521/sde1"
  },
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    connection.execute(
      "SELECT filetype, filetypeid from filetype where filetypeid < 6",
      function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
         response =  result.rows;
         console.log(response);
         res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
      });
```

This is the output

```
[["Ascii Text",1],["Binary",2],["Graphics - GIF",3],["Graphics - JPEG",4],["HTML",5]]
```

But my front end angularjs is expecting something in this format:

```
[{"filetype":"Ascii Text","filetypeid":1},{"filetype":"Binary","filetypeid":2}]
```

Does any one know what is the standard way to convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These will convert your array of arrays into an array of objects:

```js
var results = [["Ascii Text",1],["Binary",2],["Graphics - GIF",3],["Graphics - JPEG",4],["HTML",5]];

results = results.map(
  function(item) {
    return {
      filetype: item[0],
      filetypeid: item[1]
    }
  }
);

console.log(results);
```

And in ES6:

```js
var results = [["Ascii Text",1],["Binary",2],["Graphics - GIF",3],["Graphics - JPEG",4],["HTML",5]];

results = results.map(item => ({filetype: item[0], filetypeid: item[1]}));

console.log(results);
```